# How to execute method for Allowed Values in Claim-based Authorization?

Tags: .net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity

I am having 2 policies: `Readers` and `Writers`.
For each of this policies i would have a number of values belonging to them:

```
Readers: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Writers: [100,400,500]
```

This Arrays would be stored in a database / retrieved via a Http call.

How can i instead of checking the required claim value against some predefined values like here:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
               options.AddPolicy("Readers", 
                  policy =>policy.RequireClaim("UserID", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));
        });
```

Get to something like this:

```
 CheckPolicyService someService;
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Readers", 
                   policy =>policy.RequireClaim("UserID", async (userId)=>await someService.CheckClaimAsync(new Claim("UserID",userId,),"Readers"));
            });
```

How can i instead of checking that the `EmployerID` is in the given values list , instead call a service
that checks this ?

```
public class PolicyRepo
{
   public string PolicyID{get;set;}
   public string[] Users{get;set;}
}

public class CheckPolicyService
{
  private PolicyRepo [] repos {get;set;} //all policies with their allowed users
  public async Task<bool> CheckClaimAsync(Claim userClaim,string policy)
  {
      if(userClaim.Type!="UserID")
      {
         return false;
      }
      bool hasAccess=this.repos.Single(r=>r.PolicyId==policy).Users.Contains(userClaim.Value);
      return hasAccess;

  }
}


public class Controller 
{
   [Authorize(Policy="Readers")]
   public async Task ReadAsync()
   {

   }
   [Authorize(Policy="Writers")]
   public async Task WriteAsync()
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [Custom Authorization Policy Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider) is something you can use.